# MySQL Match sku in two tables, and return specific rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

So I have two tables, as outlined below. I'm trying to craft a query that will match the sku from table_2, with a sku in table_1, and upon a match return the corresponding images from table_1, and the corresponding title from table_2.

table_1

```
id  sku     title       images
=============================================
1   11-001  The_title   image-link/11-001.jpg
2   11-002  The_Title   image-link/11-002.jpg
3   11-001  The_Title   image-link/11-001.jpg
```

table_2

```
id  sku     title       images
========================================================
1   11-001  The_title   some-other-image-link/11-001.jpg
2   11-002  The_Title   some-other-image-link/11-002.jpg
3   11-001  The_Title   some-other-image-link/11-001.jpg
```

The desired output would look something like this:

```
id  sku     title               images
======================================================
1   11-001  Title-From_Table2   image-link-from-table1
2   11-002  Title-From_Table2   image-link-from-table1
3   11-001  Title-From_Table2   image-link-from-table1
```

I've tried a few different joins and approaches, but I've had no luck getting the desired output. Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is a standard inner join on the sku field.

```
select f.id, f.sku, s.title, f.images
from table_1 f
inner join table_2 s on
s.sku = f.sku
```

Note that to return only one id you need to choose wich one to return because the id of table_1 can be different from the id of table_2.

---

If you don't need eventual duplicates add a group by at the end

```
select f.id, f.sku, s.title, f.images
from table_1 f
inner join table_2 s on
s.sku = f.sku
group by f.id, f.sku, s.title, f.images
```

Answer (score 0):

From the description, sounds like you just need to join on SKU and get `select t1.id, t1.sku, t2.title, t1.images`

```
select t1.id, t1.sku, t2.title, t1.images
from table_1 t1, table_2 t2
where t1.sku = t2.sku
```